# Synonym proposal: [crontab] -> [cron]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The two tags [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron) and [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crontab) receive virtually identical questions. Indeed, it is hard to imagine situations where [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crontab) would add anything over [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron).

While [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron) is probably the more technically correct term, it seems that [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crontab) gets a steady stream of questions, and has a better tag wiki.  Note the similarities between the tag wikis!

I have proposed [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crontab) as a synonym for [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron) but don't have sufficient reputation in these tags to effectively clean them up.  I am hoping to reach a community consensus that the questions in these tags cover similar ground, and that there does not seem to be a common understanding among question authors about when one tag should be preferred over the other.

In case you are not familiar with Unix, `cron` is the scheduled execution daemon (service) and `crontab` is the name of the command used to edit its configuration files, and by extension, what we call these files.  I also notice that the less popular, informal [cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cronjob) is already a synonym for [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron).

Tangentially, I suppose the tag wikis will need to be merged before the synonym is put into place...?

Comment: Separately voting on [the synonym proposal](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/synonyms) would be useful as well.

Comment: "cron is the scheduled execution daemon (service) and crontab is the name of the command used to edit its configuration files,": that says they are different things. You need to clarify why different things should have the same tag ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the feedback; I added an intro paragraph which hopefully clarifies my thinking.

Comment: Note that this tag synonym is [already in place on Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/cron/synonyms), so that might suggest something.

Comment: They are synonyms now.

Comment: @Jon Clements is it possible for you moderators to conduct the merge of these tags as described in [Don't track tag badges for synonymized tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272092/209901) to avoid [Synonym wrecks badge progress](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326491/1983854)? Now it shows quite strange in profile like mine, with a progress in both tags: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhwEI.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A year and a half later, my proposal was accepted.