# Synonym wrecks badge progress

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-synonym-process, tag-badges

My profile page on Stack Overflow suggests I am close to being awarded a bronze badge in the tag [make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make).  However, there is no way I can achieve this goal, because the tag is (now) a synonym for [makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile).

Shouldn't badges (and scores etc) be transitioned to use the synonym target when a synonym is approved?

Comment: Can you try to change the badge you are tracking and change it back? That should recalc your progress. Does it?

Comment: @Sklivvz Shouldn't that be something the system should do automatically?

Comment: @cybermonkey I would assume the problem in this case would somehow be in your local cache, if I get what Skylivvz means.

Comment: @Laf Then the cache expiration should be set appropiately... I'm not the OP by the way.

Comment: @cybermonkey Yeah I didn't mean "your cache" as in your own cache, but as a in anyone's cache. I realize now it might have caused some confusion :-P

Comment: @cybermonkey yes, but this would force the operation, allowing me to triage the (possible) bug.

Comment: See [Don't track tag badges for synonymized tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272091/dont-track-tag-badges-for-synonymized-tags)

Comment: Also, don't forget that there's some sort of cache that takes up to 1 day to refresh.

Comment: The core of the bug, it seems to me now, is that the system should not propose a tag for tracking if it's a synonym, and retract the suggestion if one which is already being tracked is made into a synonym. Waiting for the site to remove all questions with the old tag is clearly unacceptable; I don't personally have the stamina to retag thousands of questions, and many users don't even have the rep.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with caching. The tag has been on my profile page for weeks, probably months, and I wasn't really paying attention to it until recently, when I then discovered that my efforts to nudge it above the bronze threshold were not paying off.

Comment: @tripleee IMHO the whole process with tags could be greatly improved... like having a function in the UI to trigger a batch retag for moderators without having to get the community to do it, for a start.

Comment: @cybermonkey That function exists. The problem is moderators aren't notified of new tag synonyms so unless they go looking for tags to merge, it won't get used.

Comment: @animuson: Would a custom mod flag on a question that meets the requirements for running that function or a meta post on the topic be sufficient to notify a moderator?

Comment: @Ellesedil Meta posts are preferred. The merge function itself is fairly destructive in the regard that performing a merge is completely irreversible. It's nice to have a public note laying around somewhere to note what happened, and also gives users who might be against the synonym to speak now or forever hold their peace.

Comment: I've been having trouble getting an [obvious tag synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/slim/synonyms) approved for months, simply because of the odd process.

Comment: @alexw That's a different topic altogether. I agree that it's broken for tags with few participants, but please find a different post (or ask a new question) to participate in that discussion.

Comment: @animuson You may want to post a brief answer based on your comments here. It's rather cumbersome to comb through the comments and finally run across the link to Meta.SE you posted just to figure out what's going on, and even that required noticing the most recent edit was yours and checking that you were the one who added [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: Also, [tag:broken-bydesign] is never really a very satisfying answer.